# Python - Generate random real number between range with a step size

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, random

I am using python-3.x, and I am trying to generate an initial population that contains random real numbers between 0 and 1 where these numbers should be one of the following:
0, 0.33333, 0.666667 or 1

That means the difference between these numbers is 0.33333 (1/3). I tried to modify this code in many ways but their no luck

```
import numpy as np
import random
from random import randint
from itertools import product
pop_size = 7
i_length = 2
i_min = 0
i_max = 1
level = 2
step = ((1/((2**level)-1))*(i_max-i_min))

def individual(length, min, max):
    return [ randint(min,max) for x in range(length) ]
def population(count, length, min, max):
    return [ individual(length, min, max) for x in range(count) ]

population = population(pop_size, i_length, i_min, i_max)

##count: the number of individuals in the population
##length: the number of values per individual
##min: the minimum possible value in an individual's list of values
##max: the maximum possible value in an individual's list of values
##this code was taken from :https://lethain.com/genetic-algorithms-cool-name-damn-simple/
```

I did this lines which works very well for me:

```
population2 = np.array(list(product(np.linspace(i_min, i_max, 2**level), repeat=2)))
population3 = [j for j in product(np.arange(i_min, i_max+step, step), repeat=2)]
```

but the problem it will list all the possible values which are not what I want. I want random numbers where the population size will be given

the result I want to see is smailar to (numpy array or list):

```
population = [[0, 1],
             [0, 0.3333],
             [0.3333, 1],
             [1, 0.6667],
             [0.3333, 0.6667],
             [0.6667, 0],
             [0.3333, 0.3333]]
```

keep in mind the:

```
level = 2
```

where I can calculat the the step value:

```
step = ((1/((2**level)-1))*(i_max-i_min))
```

for example, if I changed the `level = 2` to `level = 3` then it is no more using the 0.3333 it will change to 0.1428 1/7) which I will get different values.

Any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> np.random.choice([0, 1/3., 2/3., 1], size=(7,2), replace=True)
array([[0.        , 0.33333333],
       [0.33333333, 0.66666667],
       [0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.66666667, 0.        ],
       [0.33333333, 0.33333333],
       [1.        , 1.        ],
       [0.33333333, 0.33333333]])


>>> i_min = 0
>>> i_max = 1
>>> level = 3
>>> np.random.choice(np.linspace(i_min, i_max, 2**level), size=(7,2), replace=True)
array([[0.28571429, 0.14285714],
       [0.85714286, 0.57142857],
       [0.71428571, 0.42857143],
       [0.71428571, 1.        ],
       [0.14285714, 0.85714286],
       [0.        , 0.        ],
       [1.        , 0.        ]])
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but the problem with your idea it doesn't use a variable step size. for example, if I changed the `level = 2` to `level = 3` then it is no more using the 0.3333 it will change to 0.1428 1/7)

Comment: @azeez I used a fixed list but a `np.linspace` generated array is fine too. E.g. `np.random.choice(np.linspace(0,1,2**level), size=(7,2), replace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Without numpy:

```
from random import randint

def get_population(num, repeats, fraction):
 return [[randint(0, fraction)/fraction for x in range(num)] for i in range(repeats)]

print(get_population(2, 7, 3))
```

Output is:

```
[[0.3333333333333333, 0.0],
 [0.3333333333333333, 1.0],
 [1.0, 0.3333333333333333],
 [0.3333333333333333, 0.0],
 [0.0, 0.3333333333333333],
 [0.3333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666],
 [1.0, 1.0]]
```

Fraction 7:

```
print(get_population(2, 7, 7))
```

Output is:

```
[[0.8571428571428571, 0.7142857142857143],
 [0.7142857142857143, 0.14285714285714285], 
 [0.0, 0.7142857142857143], 
 [0.42857142857142855, 0.5714285714285714], 
 [0.42857142857142855, 0.7142857142857143], 
 [1.0, 0.5714285714285714], 
 [1.0, 1.0]]
```

Comment: thank you @Konstantin for your reply, what about if I changed the step value `level = 2 to level = 3`

Comment: just need to edit `randint(0, 3)/3` to **`randint(0, fraction)/fraction`** and you can change it to any you want

Comment: what do you mean by the **fraction** here, do mean the fractions module?

Comment: no, it's just a variable. fraction can be a random integer, for example `randint(0, 7)/7` for **1/7** step size. Post edited

Comment: For sure you can also replace `fraction` variable to your `(2**level)-1` syntax

Comment: Thank you very much it is very interesting, Ok but if I am not wrong you are missing the min and max values `i_min = 0 i_max = 1` variables, they can be changed to anything else . in your idea you are assuming the upper and lower bounds 0-1